# Why can I not connect to a local minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I try to join my brothers world, it will not show up for me and vice versa. This happens despite us being a few feet from each other. We currently have MCPE version 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need realms for PE to play with eachother. If I'm wrong, please correct me.